# TCriticalSection.LockCount and negative values

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi

Does **TCriticalSection.lockcount** return a negative value for the number of locks?

I have created a windows based,  multi-threaded Delphi service.  I use a number of Critical Sections within it.  Thinking I could have some deadlocks, I wanted to query how many locks were on Critical Sections.

I created my own descendant class from **TCriticalSection** and exposed a function to get the lock count:

```
type
  TEACriticalSection = class(TCriticalSection)
  function GetLockCount: Integer;
end;
implementation

function TEACriticalSection.GetLockCount: Integer;
begin
  result := FSection.lockcount;
end;
```

I am finding the number returned is always negative.  Is this the number of "waiting" processes?  Why is it negative and not positive?

Comment: Sadly the accepted answer at the dupe is hopeless. Read the most voted answer.

Comment: Yes - I came across this during my research (I actually spent a number of hours trying to find an answer before submitting to SO).  My thought was something has to be amiss - other people must run into similar problems and want to have an idea how many pending blocks a critical section has.  Sadly I guess the best explanation is hopeless.

Comment: I don't understand. That answer explains it all.